# Add Image (filter) on top of Input capture

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am looking for a solution to add an image on top of the html's:

```
<input type='file' accept= "image/*" capture>
```

This is working on all devices and browsers, and that's why I don't use getUserMedia.

So when a user opens a camera, it will have an image on top of it - like a filter

Thanks